# Split/Divide home, menu screen in 4 large parts? Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've just started using Xamarin and I'm new to C#. I've worked a lot with Java so I don't find it daunting. I'm essentially trying to develop a part of the app, that once selected, the user will be guided from the main menu, to a submenu containing the "Projects" aspect of the app.
The "Projects" Screen will allow the user to click on:
Existing Projects
New Projects
Help and Back.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
http://s4.postimg.org/qxporlja5/Screen_Shot_2014_07_22_at_21_29_56.png

Any ideas of how to get started?
UITableView looks promising but I'm not sure if that's the best/easiest way.

Thanks

Comment: If it is going to be a static list of selectable items, why not just use buttons placed directly on the view?

Comment: I would agree with @Stonz2. You can size the buttons to create the effect you are looking for pretty easily. You will need to do some calculating to make sure the buttons are the correct size on the various screens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Xamarin.Forms? The image you have looks like it might fit well with a StackLayout or a GridLayout. Check out their page: http://xamarin.com/forms. Also, Xamarin.Forms is cross-platform so you could essentially use this for Droid and WP8 if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

That looks pretty simple.

You can do this either with the designer, just lay out the views in there, and set the colors you want.

Then, once you are comfortable with that, you should adopt auto-layout (but that takes a little bit of learning).  Auto-layout will help you adjust the sizes of that depending on the form factor (iPhone 4 vs 5, vs iPad) and help you handle orientations as well as any new form factors (which has been strongly hinted as happening)